# What pyspark api calls requiere same version of python in workers in yarn-client mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

usually I run my code with different versions of Python in the driver than in the worker nodes, using yarn-client mode.

For instance, I usually use python3.5 in the driver and the default python2.6 in workers and this works pretty.

I am currently in a project where we need to call

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame
```

But this seems to try to execute this sentence in python in the workers and then I got the requirement of installing the same version of python in workers which is what I am trying to avoid.

So, For using "sqlContext.createDataFrame" it is a requirement to have the same python version in driver and workers ?

And if so, which other "pure" pyspark.sql api call would also have this requirement?

Thanks,
Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, the same Python verion is the requirement in general. Some API call may not fail because there is no Python executor in use but it is not a valid configuration.
- Every call that interacts with Python code, like `udf` or `DataFrame.rdd.*` will trigger the same exception.
- If you want to avoid upgrading cluster Python then use Python 2 on the driver.

Comment: But, all the rest of api call does not require same python in workers. Why this needs it ? For instance, toPandas() does no requires this.

Comment: In general Spark requires the same version of Python on each machine. Some parts of API just don't use Python executors so you never get to the condition where your code fails. But it doesn't make it OK.

Answer (score 1):

In general, many pyspark operations are just a wrapper to calling spark operations on the JVM. For these operations it doesn't matter what version of python is used in the worker because no python is executed on the worker, only JVM operations.

Examples of such operations include reading a dataframe from file, all built-in functions which do not require python objects/functions as input etc.

Once a function requires an actual python object or function this becomes a little trickier.
Let's say for example that you want to use a UDF and use lambda x: x+1 as the function.
Spark doesn't really know what the function is. Instead it serializes it and sends it to the worker who de-serialize it in turn.

For this serialization/de-serialization process to work, the versions of both sides need to be compatible and that is often not the case (especially between major versions).

All of this leads us to createDataFrame. If you use RDD as one of the parameters for example, the RDD would contain python objects as the records and these would need to be serialized and de-serialized and therefore must have the same version.